# Mutt email - .muttrc syntax for message-hook with sed and tac

Tags: sed, mutt, tac

I am having trouble getting the correct syntax for a message-hook in Mutt (neomutt).

I receive daily emails that I cannot ignore from a school's software package. The arrive as an inline giant wall of  tags.

Although lynx does a good job on 99% of the html emails that I receive, these emails have html content labeled as plain/txt and in inbox they display like [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/1LgNZ8q)

Despite the fool's errand of using sed to parse html, (amusing rant on Stack Overflow duly noted) I have a sed command that works great.

I just only want to apply the sed command to emails from 1 particular sender (the remailer for the offending software program used by the school to send emails)

For this reason, I attempted to use a muttrc message-hook.

When added to the muttrc, this line works as intended. All text between < and > in the message is removed from all emails globally in mutt.

```
set display_filter = "tac | sed 's/<[^>]*>/<>/g' | tac"
```

[The command works as expected](https://imgur.com/a/IM0j8FN)

However, this also removes the displayed email addresses.

```
Mrs Teacher <teacher1@school.org>
```

becomes

```
Mrs Teacher <>
```

Thus, I want to use the muttrc command in a message hook to apply to emails from this remailer domain and not to any other emails that I receive.

```
message-hook '~e email@school.org' 'set display_filter = "tac | sed 's/<[^>]*>/<>/g' | tac"'
```

Expected result:
Emails from any other sender than email@school.org will display normally
Emails from email@school.org will have all text between < > filtered out

Actual result:
Emails from any other sender than email@school.org display normally
Emails from email@school.org display a blank page in Mutt. No text whatsoever.

I suspect the message is being stripped of html tags, then fed into lynx, which displays a blank page.

I have tried various combinations of '`" and adding "exec" to the message-hook, but most of them give an error when Mutt is executed.

What can I do differently in the message-hook to make the correct syntax?

Alternatively, can I use a message-hook to force emails from only this sender to be classified correctly as MIME type html instead of plain/text, so that lynx displays them correctly?

edit: formatting, potential workaround

Comment: Use `formail` to get the email into a standard format before you try to parse it. I haven't used it in a while but just google it, https://www.google.com/search?q="mutt"+"formail".